# Stack Exchange is developing a new Code of Conduct

Tags: discussion, moderation, policy, code-of-conduct

[The second draft of our Code of Conduct is available for feedback and review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312850/311001) over on Meta.SE. This is an update to/evolution of the "Be Nice" policy which currently guides site use and moderation. Importantly:

> This just codifies the rules that we already use, moderation is still at the discretion of the individual moderators, and we've clarified that in this revision. – [Tim Post♦ Jul 19 at 16:43](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312850/the-second-draft-of-our-code-of-conduct-is-available-for-feedback-and-review#comment1024785_312850)

If you're interested, go ahead and take a look at the main post on meta.SE, follow linked conversations and read the suggestions--or even make your own!

---

Please note that conversation here won't necessarily be seen by SE employees. If you have concerns about/suggestions for the Code of Conduct they should be made on meta.SE. If you have concerns about/suggestions for the *implementation of the CoC here on RPG.SE*, then I suppose those would go well here where the elected mods can take a look and consider.